# Временная память в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю карточную игру где выкладывается на игровую зону карты, но также их нужно забирать если ошибся, как сделать чтобы при выкладывании карты игра запоминала какая это карта, и в каком столбике (пытался сделать с помощью переменных, но настраивать 32 переменки муторно) Я программист ниже-среднего

Comment: используйте массивы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете сделать простую структуру. Пример:

```cs
struct Card
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public string name;
    public int level;
    public Color32 Color;
}
```

А если ещё и глобально  надо можете сделать двумерный массив.

```cs
Card[,] deck = new Card[5, 5];
```